# Flutter Getx improper use of a GetX has been detected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have simple Getx Controller like this

```
class UserController extends GetxController {
  var user = UserModel();


  void addUser(UserModel data) {
    user = data;
    update();
  }
}
```

I am adding data in userModel like this

```
   usercontroller.addUser(UserModel(
        userAge: value['userAge'],
        userEmail: value['userEmail'],
        userID: value['userID'],
        userImage: value['userImage'],
        userName: value['userName'],
        userPassion: value['passion']));
    globalUserId = value['userID'];
    // print(usercontroller.user.userName.value);
```

After adding data I can print it and its working.

But now I need to show in on different page and I am showing by GetX and its showing error   `[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.` I don't know what is causing issue but when I am adding data in user after this I can check by print that its adding successfully but Getx is causing issue in this.

```
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: GetX<UserController>(
            builder: (_) => SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '${user_controller.user.userName}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.04,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not use proper getx in your code. for manage state in getx and read live change data you need to define object with obs. look into below code

```
class UserController extends GetxController {
 var user = UserModel().obs;


  void addUser(UserModel data) {
    user.value = data;
    update();
  }
}
```

and in your widget put obx for observe value

```
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Obx(
            () => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                '${user_controller.user.value.userName}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize:25),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetX` was not used properly

After creating your controller like this

```
    class UserController extends GetxController {
      var user = UserModel();


      void addUser(UserModel data) {
        user = data;
        update();
      }
    }
```

`Wrap` the `SingleChildScrollView` in a `GetBuilder`

```
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: GetBuilder<UserController>(
        builder: (ctrl) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                '${ctrl.user.userName}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: size.height * 0.04,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

I hope this helps.